# commondialog is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

This is my first real shot at .NET so apologies in advance if this is a dumb question. I am upgrading a VB6 to .NET (using VS 2008).

I get the error "**Commondialog is a type and cannot be used as an expression**"

Can anyone help me please? If possible can you provide a full answer as I am easily confused!

Cheers!

The code is:

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdBrowse.Click
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: CommonDialog variable was not upgraded Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="671167DC-EA81-475D-B690-7A40C7BF4A23"'
    With CommonDialog
        .InitialDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: Filter has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="9B7D5ADD-D8FE-4819-A36C-6DEDAF088CC7"'
        .Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: FileOpenConstants constant FileOpenConstants.cdlOFNHideReadOnly was upgraded to OpenFileDialog.ShowReadOnly which has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="DFCDE711-9694-47D7-9C50-45A99CD8E91E"'
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: MSComDlg.CommonDialog property CommonDialog.Flags was upgraded to CommonDialogOpen.CheckFileExists which has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="DFCDE711-9694-47D7-9C50-45A99CD8E91E"'
        .CheckFileExists = True
        .CheckPathExists = True
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: MSComDlg.CommonDialog property CommonDialog.Flags was upgraded to CommonDialogOpen.ShowReadOnly which has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="DFCDE711-9694-47D7-9C50-45A99CD8E91E"'
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: FileOpenConstants constant FileOpenConstants.cdlOFNHideReadOnly was upgraded to OpenFileDialog.ShowReadOnly which has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="DFCDE711-9694-47D7-9C50-45A99CD8E91E"'
        .ShowReadOnly = False
        .FileName = txtEnterValue.Text
        .ShowDialog()
        txtEnterValue.Text = .FileName
    End With
    RefreshFileDetails()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdBrowse.Click
    Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.InitialDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
        ofd.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        ofd.CheckFileExists = True
        ofd.ShowReadOnly = True
        ofd.FileName = txtEnterValue.Text
        If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            txtEnterValue.Text = ofd.FileName
            RefreshFileDetails()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer - I can now get it to build which is a great start .... your help is very much appreciated